# Why is my block aligned to the bottom of the line? (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, language-lawyer

I'm trying to get a box aligned to the left of it's containing block: putting a note in the column of text. I have the left position correct, but the top appears to be aligned with the bottom of the line, and not the top.

See the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/j2EkZ/)

[image]

HTML Snippet:

```
 ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam 
 eget libero <span class='left-hanger'>Short</span> 
 <b>egestas mattis</b> sit amet vitae augue.
```

CSS Snippet:

```
.left-hanger {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: -6em;
        width: 5em;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

I'd like to know why it is aligned this way. I am interested in specific details referenced from the standard which indicates it would be aligned this way. The three browsers I tested agree, so it seems like it is standard behaviour.

*Note: I'm not really interested in a "fix" for this issue here, but rather an explanation. That is, why does my CSS say to align the top of the block with the bottom of the line?*

Comment: Are you looking to move the yellow label to the top left of the paragraph ?

Comment: @LeoTAbraham, the use-case would be to align the top of the label with the top of the bold text. However, here I'm primarily curious here and wish to have an explanation of the demonstrated behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is absolutely positioned, therefore the following applies:

> [**9 Visual formatting model - 9.3.1 Choosing a positioning scheme: 'position' property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position)
>
> The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties. **These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block**. Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings.

In this instance, you haven't set a `top`/`bottom` value, therefore the values are assumed to be the default `auto`.

> [**9 Visual formatting model - 9.3.2 Box offsets: 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props)
>
> **'top'**
>
> **Initial: auto**
>
> This property specifies how far an **absolutely positioned box's top margin edge is offset below the top edge of the box's containing block**. For relatively positioned boxes, the offset is with respect to the top edges of the box itself (i.e., the box is given a position in the normal flow, then offset from that position according to these properties).

---

### Visual demonstration

Position of the element with `position:static` (default)

> [image]

Position of the element when it is absolutely positioned with `top`/`bottom` values of `auto`.

Notice how they are vertically positioned on the same line? This is the exact behavior described in the documentation.

> [image]

It's also worth noting that the element wasn't a block level element in the above images. It was inline, therefore it appears on the same line. In the image in your question, the elements appear on the next line because they are block level. (that's why it's one line off - go look) This is a typical distinction between the display of elements.

---

**For more information**: Read the linked documentation, "[Visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)"

Comment: So the vertical alignment difference is due to the difference between `block` and `inline` type. The block type is positioned on the next line (naturally, as that is what block layout is meant to do). If I understand, then `inline-block` should also be top-aligned as desired. Testing this, it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please try this code.

    - Put position: relative on p

     #one p {
                 position:relative;
            }

    -Put top:0 on .left-hanger

     .left-hanger {
             display: block;
             position: absolute;
             left: -6em;
             width: 5em;
             top:16px
             background: yellow;
         }

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/4a38b/
```

Comment: I'm not looking to "fixing" the layout issue, but rather get an explanation of why my CSS results in that layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the use of

```
position:absoulte
```

in css.

Comment: I'm looking for a concrete explanation of why this is aligning the top of the block to the bottom of the line.